# query deleted custom object records from recyle bin

Tags: data-loader, data-export, recycle-bin

Query to get records from recycle bin

Comment: Please revisit [ask]. This post does not contain a *question*.

Comment: I will surely take care in future Adrian.

Comment: You don't care to **[edit]** this post to contain one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Apex Data Loader, use the Export All button instead of the Export button. This will allow you to query deleted rows:

```
SELECT Id FROM SomeObject__c WHERE IsDeleted = TRUE
```

You can then use the Apex Data Loader to restore the files using its undelete option.

Comment: Thanks Sfdcfox. I got the records list through dataloaer . But when i am looking to find in recyle bin to undelete them, there are thousands with same name and lastmodifieddate. Any way i can filter them. Recycle bin coloums are only: Name, type, deletedby,deletedate. any idea how can i know which one is mine

Comment: @DavidMycka You can query additional fields, too. The recycle bin isn't as functional as the API.

Comment: I am query all fields from dataloader. I got my record in Excel File only 3 records are there . But when i am trying to look same in recycle bin UI, i can see thousands of records which same name and delete data. How can i know which one is mine. Any idea if can add any coloumns to recycle bin List view

Comment: @DavidMycka No; the recycle bin shows ALL objects that have been deleted. You retrieved 3 records just from ONE object, so that's all you can see. Either there are no more or they have been purged.

Comment: Thanks for response. I got 3 from dataloader when put recordtype filter in export query. My next step is to do undelete them from recycle bin when i am looking at GUI for recylebin all have same name like BA-1, how can i filter those

Comment: @DavidMycka The Apex Data Loader has an undelete option. There's no need to use the GUI.

Comment: my dataloader dont show undelete option. Is there i can do for that. There are only, insert,update,delete,update,export and exportall

Comment: @DavidMycka I'm sorry, it looks like I was wrong. It happens. Try using the workbench: https://workbench.developerforce.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use below query :

```
select Id from Customobject__c where isdeleted = true ALL rows
```

when we are deleting any records from salesforce stamps the isdeleted value as true,otherwise by default the value was false and you can not modify the value.

After getting all the records from the record just perform the **undelete** operation on the list then you can get all the deleted records.

I think it will solve your purpose.

Comment: ALL ROWS is not for the Data Loader, though.